# What is EH-Tcp?

Tags: remote-desktop, xendesktop

On a XenDesktop VDI I see in HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations keys "Console" and "RDP-Tcp" as expected, but also a key "EH-Tcp" with a WdName value "Microsoft RDP 5.2". This is a Windows 7 machine. What is "EH-Tcp"?

And why is there no key "ICA-Tcp"? Does XenDesktop not use ICA?

Answer (score 1):

XenDesktop use the ICA channel between the VM and the endpoint via the **Citrix Virtual Desktop Agent (now named Virtual Delivery agent)** installed in the machine.

It's not adding any entry in the TerminalServer subkey.

EH-TCP seem to have been introduced from Vista+. Seem related to Remote-FX.

There is a diagram for XenDesktop;

[image]